# Docker build strategy with Maven

Tags: maven, docker, dockerfile, openshift, openshift-origin

There are several ways to make a build for Openshift, one of them is [Docker build strategy](https://docs.okd.io/latest/architecture/core_concepts/builds_and_image_streams.html#docker-build)

I do have a Dockerfile in the root of my repository:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8

...


RUN mvn clean package

...
```

When I execute

> oc new-build https://github.com/myrepo

it succeeds, but:

> oc start-build ...

fails complaining that cannot find a `pom.xml` file in the working directory (which is `/`).

Using

```
RUN echo `find . pom.xml`
```

I found out that the `pom.xml` file is nowhere to be found.

**How can I make it working? Also, is my approach a correct one?**

Comment: you need to add a COPY statement in your Dockerfile before the RUN statement to have your project files available within the container. Maybe there are images available with more suitable defaults for okd (don't know that). You are using the official maven image that does not come with a lot of assumptions. There are a lot of ways to run builds using docker or build containers. It's impossible to say if your approach is correct - we can't know what you want to achieve. But it does not look wrong either. Should do something :)

Comment: @wemu I solve it already with a COPY instruction followed by a WORKDIR. But I got stuck when trying to ADD the generated jar to the image: file not found error.

Comment: the jar file you create should already be in the image. so the add probably needs some parameters. I would think what you do is a multi stage build: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: @wemu I've got it working by using `mvn clean install` instead of `mvn clean package` then copy the jar from .m2 location. Anyway, this approach is wrong since the entire .m2 folder goes into image along with the maven installation. The idea of  a multi stage build sounds very good, I'll try it. BTW, if you make an answer with all your suggestions, I'll accept it.

Comment: will do. points are points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to add a COPY statement to the Dockerfile so the project files are available to maven inside the running container. Then start the build with the RUN statement.

Since you probably will not run the resulting docker image you want to create on the maven image, you may have a look at [docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). It allows running your build with one image and pass files into a new image based on a different image.

This is a common approach to create applications inside docker images using docker build images during creation. So it all looks good so far.